# Generate an infinite amount of nodes and destroy by clicking on them

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to generate an infinite amount of nodes that fall from the top of the screen and destroy them by just clicking on them, it is simple but I am having serious problems with it. When the nodes are generated by the loop I can only generate one and it starts moving instead of falling vertically. It also disappears and appears constantly.
Here is my code, hope you can help.
Thank you!!

```
import SpriteKit

class DestroyScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate{


var velocity:CGFloat = 0
let scoreText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial Rounded MT Bold")
var score = 0
var lastYieldTimeInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastUpdateTimerInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var gameOver = false


var alien:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circuloAzulArt")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -velocity)
}

func addAlien(){





    var alien:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circuloAzulArt")
    alien.name = "alien"
    alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: alien.size.width/2)
    alien.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var actionArray2:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    alien.removeFromParent()
    if gameOver == false{


        let minX = alien.size.width/2

        let maxX = self.frame.size.width - alien.size.width/2

        let rangeX = maxX - minX


        let position:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)

        alien.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height + alien.size.height)

            self.addChild(alien)

        let minDuration = 3


        let duration = Int(minDuration)



        actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

        actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

        alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))




    }

}

func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval){
    var randomNum = Double(arc4random_uniform(20))
    var xTime = ((randomNum / 20) + 0.25)
    lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if (lastYieldTimeInterval > xTime){
        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        randomNum = Double(arc4random_uniform(25))
        addAlien()
    }

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    var timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTimerInterval
    lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime
    if score < 60{
        velocity = CGFloat(score*3)
    }else{
        velocity = CGFloat(210)
    }

    if (timeSinceLastUpdate > 1){
        timeSinceLastUpdate = 1/60
        lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime
    }


    updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.alien{

            alien.removeFromParent()
            score++
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you add an alien you remove the last alien with this line of code:
alien.removeFromParent()

You have to create a new variable node in the addAlien() function and give the node a name

for example:

```
var alien:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "alien")
alien.name = "alien"
```

Then you can remove the alien in the touchesBegan function by checking the node name

```
let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

if (node.name == "alien") {

}
```

And for the gravity you should move `self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -velocity)` to the didMoveToView() function and change the last parameter to a constant

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! IT WORKS. I can't give you a vote up now, but when i get 15 of reputation i will.